# How to select a constant value in EFCore 3.1 without custom sql

Tags: entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I would like EFCore to generate the equivalent of "select name, color, 'notapplicable' as position from table

I have multiple entities in a context where I need to pass the IQueryable to a generic function that will GroupBy(x => x.Position).  If I mark Position as NotMapped the GroupBy won't execute server side.  I have tried all sorts of combinations trying to use ValueGeneratedOn... and ComputedSql but with no success.

In the below example, ActivityWithRealQty has a config that maps all 3 fields to columns in a db, but ActivityWithStaticQty does not have a field in the DB for Quantity.  However, I want it to return 1 as a static value so that the GroupBy works correctly server side.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private IEnumerable<ResultActivity> GroupData(IQueryable<IActivity> data)
        {
            var rtn = data.GroupBy(result => new
            {
                result.Name,
                result.Title
            })
            .Select(x => new ResultActivity()
            { 
                Name = x.Key.Name,
                Title = x.Key.Title,
                Quantity = x.Sum(n => n.Quantity)
            })
            .ToList();

            return rtn;
        }
    }

    public class ResultActivity
    {
        public ResultActivity()
        {
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IActivity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActivityWithStaticQty : IActivity
    {
        public string Name { get ; set ; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; } = 1;
    }

    public class ActivityWithRealQty : IActivity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it helps if you show us the code. Put together an example as part of your question.

Comment: @Mo-Gang Code added to original post

Comment: I guess `GorupBy` is not available in EFCore 3.1

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath WHen you GroupBy it runs server side, and since the field doesn't exist in teh table, it fails.  Thats the purpose of need to "synthetically" use a static value in the generated sql